# How to delete an item from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    var arr = [
                     {id:2,date:'2010-10-03',des:'goodday'},
                     {id:3,date:'2011-02-13',des:'badday'},
                     {id:4,date:'2011-04-03',des:'niceday'}
                   ];
```

Now I want to delete `{id:3,date:'2011-02-13',des:'badday'}` , and then the arr should be

```
        var arr = [
                     {id:2,date:'2010-10-03',des:'goodday'},
                     {id:4,date:'2011-04-03',des:'niceday'}
                   ];
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assume the id fields in you Objects are unique you can do the following to delete it.  The function to use is [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
    var arr = [
        {
        id: 2,
        date: '2010-10-03',
        des: 'goodday'},
    {
        id: 3,
        date: '2011-02-13',
        des: 'badday'},
    {
        id: 4,
        date: '2011-04-03',
        des: 'niceday'}
    ];

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].id == 3){
            arr.splice(i, 1);  //removes 1 element at position i 
            break;
        }
    }

console.log(arr);  
//should give you 
//                      var arr = [
//                               {id:2,date:'2010-10-03',des:'goodday'},
//                               {id:4,date:'2011-04-03',des:'niceday'}
//                          ];
```

Answer (score 1):

See here:

http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2008/javascript-remove-element-from-array

Comment: That's impossible, as the answer you've marked as the solution uses the splice method.

Comment: Splice is right, but indexOf can't work in my case. It's not the complete answer

Answer (score 0):

`arr.splice(1,1);` will remove the object at `arr[1]`, 
and `arr[2]` will slide into its place.